# How to set a ToolTip and ContextMenu assigned to all controls defined in ListView.ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, tooltip

I am using my own definition of ItemTemplate

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
        ...
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

The stack panel ownes several contols. The purpose is to popup the same ContextMenu if the user right clicks on any control of the stack panel and display the same tooltip when a mouse is over a control.

Is there a possibility to do the tooltip/contextmenu assignment in a single place rather that to do this individually for each control?

Comment: *popup the same tool tip if the user right click on any control* You mean context Menu?

Comment: Oh. sorry. Context menu. But it would be interesting to know how to do single assignment for the tooltip.

Comment: For all the controls in that template. you need same tool tip to be displayed?

Comment: @Prajwal. yes the same Tooltip and the same ContextMenu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a possibility to do the tooltip/contextmenu assignment in a single place rather that to do this individually for each control?

Set the ContextMenu/Tooltip property of the StackPanel and its value will be inherited by the child controls, i.e. you will see the same ContextMenu/Tooltip when you right-click on or hover over any of the StackPanel's child controls:

```
<ListView x:Name="lv">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="..." />
                    </ContextMenu>
                </StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                <StackPanel.ToolTip>
                    <ToolTip>
                        <TextBlock>Tooltip...</TextBlock>
                    </ToolTip>
                </StackPanel.ToolTip>
                <Button Content="Button"/>
                <TextBlock Text="..." />
                <ComboBox>
                    <ComboBoxItem>1</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>2</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>3</ComboBoxItem>
                </ComboBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```